# Where are dircolors defined for pantheon terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Although pantheon-terminal does actually appear to be applying colours to filenames, it is not those defined in `$LS_COLORS`. For example `ls` should display executable files as bright green (`ex=01;32`), though is instead using a barely visible gray.

I understand if the UX designers wish to apply a separate colour scheme in pantheon-terminal to blend better with the rest of the interface, though the colours getting applied now are unworkable. To test yourself view the output of `ls /bin` in both a pantheon-terminal and a VT (*Ctrl+Alt+F1*). In the pantheon-terminal selecting the text with a cursor will show a silhouette of the 'missing' text. Colours **are** displayed correctly in the VT.

[image: pantheon-terminal ls example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh. I found the *palette* key located in dconf tools, in

```
org.pantheon.terminal.settings
```

Clicking **Set to Default** has made the colours much nicer. You can also run this command:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette
```

I'm not sure why this was necessary as I've never changed any of these settings before. Either way it works great now.

**Edit:** In hindsight I suspect this was caused by elementary tweaks.