# Revert to default color scheme in Pantheon-Terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, color, default

I was playing around with the color schemes in the terminal and now I'd like to set it all back to the default including the background transparency which seems to no longer be working.

I have tried uninstalling an reinstalling through app center and purging through the xterm "sudo apt purge pantheon-terminal" then reinstalling "sudo apt install pantheon-terminal". But the color scheme remains. There must be a config file that stays even after it's removed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can reset terminal palette to default with `dconf` or via the command line:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette
```

To set background transparency you can change the `background` key at the same path. Its last value is between 1 (no transparency) and 0 (full transparency)

See [Where are dircolors defined for pantheon terminal?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/277/where-are-dircolors-defined-for-pantheon-terminal?rq=1) as well

Comment: Thank you. That did set the color palette back. Any idea how to get back the transparency?

Comment: You can play with the last number of the `background` key at the same path, it is between 1 (no transparency) and 0 (full transparency)

Comment: so changing the hex codes for colors does change the opacity to be completely transparent. But it cannot be tweaked otherwise. Looking at the pantheon css file it has the following code for the terminal but it seems to be overridden by some other setting                            /************
 * Terminal *
 ***********/

PantheonTerminalPantheonTerminalWindow.background {
    background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: In Elementary Tweaks you can change the background color and transparency of the terminal. Solved. Thanks!

Comment: If it is "solved" you should accept the answer so that other peuple know this as well.

Answer (score 0):

elementary tweaks can be used to change the color and transparency of the terminal along with gsettings reset org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette as mentioned above by lemonslice to get the colors back to default.

[image: elementary tweaks]